# C I am Getting Wrong Output

Tags: c, compiler-errors, ide, output, ascii

I have a C code, When I run the code, different symbols appear where there should be underscores.

```
int main(void){
    char matrix[32][63];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;j<32;i++){
        for(j=0;j<63;j++){
            matrix[i][j]='_';
        }
    }
    int n;
    printf("Enter number of iteration: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fillOnes(matrix,0,31,32,n);
    for(i=0;i<32;i++){
        for(j=0;j<63;j++){
            printf("%c",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

why am i getting output like this instead of underscore and how can i fix it.

[image]

Comment: You used one j instead of one i in the first for loop

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: consider using [`memset`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) instead of rolling your own initialization loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments by @Sedenion

Your loop intializing your matrix has an error.

```
int i,j;
for(i=0;j<32;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<63;j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j]='_';
    }
}
```

Do you see anything wrong here? :)